# Object colour becomes pale inside a transparent object

Tags: objects, transparency, lighting

i have a whiskey in a glass, and its showing as intended[image]

but when i tilt the camera angle to a certain angle, the whiskey inside became pale[image]

does anybody know whats causing this? i've tried adjusting the principle bsdf, nothing affect by it, i can only pinpoint that the glass is the reason it becomes pale, because when i remove the glass, it doesnt happen to the whiskey inside. the only solution i've found right now is to make the glass fully transparent, but then it will look like my character is holding an invinsible glass

Comment: If you're using Eevee, you won't correctly see an object with glass material behind another one, so you need to use another method, like using a mix between glossy and transparent for one of the two objects, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: its over 100mb, can i still share it? or shouldi just share the glass object?

Comment: yes please share the glass and liquid only

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7XxyNONG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7XxyNONG/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eevee, an object that has a *Glass* node or *Transmission* at 1 won't let correctly see another object that has *Alpha Blend* selected or *Screen Space Refraction* activated, so you need to find a trick to make your glass work.

For example you can mix *Glossy* and *Transparent*, with an *Input > Layer Weight* as factor, to make your glass:

[image]

[image]

For the liquid, make it *Opaque* in the material settinfs and give it a bit of *Roughness* so that it looks a bit opaque:

[image]

You can also mix the setup with a *Glass* node (or a *Principled BSDF* with *Transmission* at 1). In that case don't forget to activate the *Screen Space Reflections*, then the *Refraction* option in the *Render* panel
:

[image]

[image]

Comment: awesome,. ill try this, and let you know

Comment: okay it works, i turn off the backface culling, and it works, thanks man :D

Comment: I've edited with another solution, a glass node alone won't give a good result but you can try the second setup I show